# SpriteKit low performance

Tags: ios, performance, animation, drawing, sprite-kit

I have an app, that in one screen it has randomly positioned 800 - 1200 images all over the entire screen (small dots - see .png attachment). I tried that with UIImageView, Layers, UIViews, but the performance was always terrible, so I decided to use SpriteKit in this ViewController, to take advantage of device's OpenGL. The boost was really noticeable, but still the performance is not acceptable.

I'm fading out and in 1/3 of all the images (dots) 10/sec.

Any Ideas, how to increase the performance? It's only a couple of hundreds 13px x 13px (retina) .PNGs :)

Here's the .png:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have a retina image that's 13x13 pixels?! Grrr... :p

Comment: Is that in the simulator or on the device ? 800-1200 is a bunch either way, even without the fading which will have a significant effect on performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can I put this ... it's just a lot of sprites, it may not get much faster no matter what, specifically not with alpha blending (fading).

Perhaps you can simulate the effect using particles, they're faster to render than the same number of sprites but you have less influence over particles.

Also be sure you test performance on a real device, iOS Simulator's software rendering is very slow.

Comment: I'm testing it on a device, I think I'll figure out, how to cut out the fading I guess

Answer (score 1):

You, my friend, need to be using [SKEmitterNode](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).

In Xcode, you select **File -> New -> File...** and in the **Resources** section select **SpriteKit Particle File**. Supply it with your image and set up the parameters to create the desired effect. Voila!

Comment: Hi, thx for the tip, but unfortunately emitter's not what I need